# Pandas groupby.agg removes columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've read the other questions regarding similar issues but i still couldn't figure out how to overcome this.

This expression loses all my df columns except the one on which i groupby on and another column (do not know why that in particular).

`df = df.groupby('Full_name').agg(';'.join).reset_index()`

The solutions given in the other questions was this `reset_index()` but it does not work in my case. How do i avoid this [automatic-exclusion-of nuisance-columns otherwise](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#automatic-exclusion-of-nuisance-columns)?

Thing is i'm using the same expression on other dataframes and it works like a charm.

Comment: Can you add some data sample? Or what is `print (df.info())` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert all columns to `string`s:

```
df = df.astype(str).groupby('Full_name').agg(';'.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: This worked. I'll read about this astype(str) so i can understand why... Thank you!